# Why (0x7FFFFFFF >> 31) + 1 is zero?

Tags: python, linux

In python command line, it gives 1 and I want this answer.
But 'Putty' gives me 0,  and I don't know why? Could you guess?

Comment: `putty` is *not* your command interpreter on Linux. It probably is `bash`. So read the [documentation of `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: Since when Putty does calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putty is an ssh client, not a shell. In bash, which you're probably running on:

```
$ echo $(( (0x7FFFFFFF >> 31) + 1 ))
1
```